# React: Define ref prop on immediate descendant?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to create a wrapper component to handle Outside Clicks of components.

There are two things I'm trying to avoid, which may not be possible.

- Avoid creating an almost redundant `<div />` to handle the `ref` to my `<OutsideClick />` component.
- Avoid having to handle `this.props.passedInRef` each time I want to wrap a component.

The cleanest implementation i can get thusfar is using a HOC as follows. You'll see I also tried to use `React.cloneElement()` but I've left if commented out.

```js
const onOutsideClick = (Component) => {
  class OnOutsideClick extends React.PureComponent {

    capturedEvents = ['touchend', 'click'];

    componentDidMount() {
      this.capturedEvents.forEach((event) => {
        document.addEventListener(event, this.handleOutsideClick, true);
      });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.capturedEvents.forEach((event) => {
        document.removeEventListener(event, this.handleOutsideClick, true);
      });
    }

    handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
      if (!this.wrapperRef.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log('handled Outside Click');
      }
    }

    setWrapperRef = (node) => {
      this.wrapperRef = node;
    }

    // render() {
    //   return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    //     ref: this.setWrapperRef,
    //   });
    // }

    render() {
      return <Component ref={this.setWrapperRef} {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return OnOutsideClick;
};
```

This gets the following error on click: `_this.wrapperRef.contains is not a function at HTMLDocument.OnOutsideClick._this.handleOutsideClick`.

I can get it working if I change the render method to:

```js
render() {
      return <Component forwardRef={this.setWrapperRef} {...this.props} />;
    }
```

and inside Descendant Component render method I must define:

```
<div ref={this.props.forwardRef}>
    ...
</div>
```

This feels like I'm dirtying a descendant. Is it possible to pass the ref to the descendant simply because it's a descendant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle it.

**First:** As you suggested, you can pass on the ref as a prop with different name and then attach it to the elements div

**Second:** you can make use of `forwardRef` api to forward the ref to the component which would look like

```
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref}>{/* content here */}</div>
));
```

**Third:** you can do avoid, forwarding ref altogether by using `React.findDOMNode`. However, its not a recommended way and you must forward the refs as much as possible

```
handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
  if (!ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.wrapperRef).contains(e.target)) {
    console.log('handled Outside Click');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
Would the third option potentially require the `<OutsideClick />` component to have a wrapping div or is `ref={...}` just defined on the `Component` by the HOC wrapper?

Comment: The third options doesn't require you to make any changes to how you render the Elements. You don't need a wrapping div